# Битовый сдвиг для решения мат. примеров

Tags: c, битовые-операции

У меня есть функция `y = (a/4 + 2*b) * 7`  мне нужно решить ее используя операции сдвига и поразрядные логические операции (`&`, `|`, `~`) если с `a/4` и `2*b` все понятно, то как быть с 7? 
Я пытался записать как-то так:

```
Y = ((pdev->a>>2)|(pdev->b<<1)<<3);
```

Я 7 разложил на степени двойки (очень даже безуспешно). Так как же быть с такими числами?

Comment: А как вы обошлись с суммированием, можно посмотреть? `a/4+2*b` как вы вычисляете? Именно суммирование?

Comment: @Harry использовал логичиское или(  | )
В той строчке кода что я скинул оно есть

Comment: И что будет при сложении, скажем, 3 и 6? 011 и 110? 111 - т.е. 3+6 равно 7? Я видел ваше `|`, но решил, что это вы просто не то сбросили...

Comment: @Harry хорошо `|` я заменю просто +, но как быть с 7?

Comment: Так + разрешен или нет? Может, и минус тоже разрешен? :)

Comment: @Harry в этом случае да(прошу прощения за некорректное описание проблемы),вся моя проблема заключается в числе 7 ,я не понимаю как его представить соответствующей формуле A << N= A * 2^N...

Comment: 7 = 4 + 2 + 1 = 8 - 1 - этого достаточно?

Comment: Ну если плюс (а тогда уж и минус, небось?) разрешён, то какие проблемы? для умножения на 7 используйте несколько копий операнда.

Comment: Скажем, так: `Y = (((pdev->a>>2)+(pdev->b<<1))<<3)-((pdev->a>>2)+(pdev->b<<1));`.

Comment: Вот видите, Akina уже догадался :)

Comment: В ассемблере для умножения на 7 обычно делают сдвиг на три бита и одно отрицание. Вопрос, можно ли отнимать? {x*7 == ((x<<3)-x)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По идее, так:

```
y=(a>>2)+(b<<1); // y=a/4+b*2
y+=(y<<1)+(y<<2); // y=y+2*y+4*y=7*y
```

Заменять операцию + логическими операциями, скорее всего, по условиям задачи не нужно, так как результат будет слишком сложен (из-за необходимости учитывать сквозные переносы) и менее оптимизирован.

Или так:

```
y=(a>>2)+(b<<1); // y=a/4+b*2
y=(y<<3)-y; // y=y*8-y=7*y
```

Второй вариант на 1 операцию короче, но первый более предпочтительный, так как во втором варианте максимум значения будет в промежуточном вычислении 8*y, а не в конечном результате. Если при 8*y произойдет переполнение, результат будет разрушен. Первый же вариант в таком случае отработает нормально (конечно, если при 7*y не произойдет переполнения).